# Update jsonb object to contain key/value from parent row

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with an id column and a jsonb column.

I want to update the jsonb object on each row to contain the id value of the 'parent' row.

Create my setup like this:

```
CREATE TABLE people ( 
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    meta jsonb
);


insert into people (meta) values 
    ('{"age": 10}'),
    ('{"age": 15}'),
    ('{"age": 20}')
;
```

Which results in this:

```
id  meta
1   {"age": 10}
2   {"age": 15}
3   {"age": 20}
```

I want to migrate data so that it looks like this:

```
id  meta
1   {"id": 1, "age": 10}
2   {"id": 2, "age": 15}
3   {"id": 3, "age": 20}
```

Postgres version: 10.7

I got kind of close using a subquery but it wasn't quite working. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate the data in the `id` column?

Comment: This is a contrived example @a_horse_with_no_name, I just wanted to simplify my problem.

Actually I want to move a key from 'parent' row into the 'child' meta and then remove it from the 'parent' row.  I will eventually be moving the meta out into a new table though as I have realised that it was not the right way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `jsonb_build_object()` and then concatenate the result to the existing `jsonb` object:

```
SELECT meta || jsonb_build_object('id', id)
FROM people;
```

To actually `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE people
SET meta = meta || jsonb_build_object('id', id);
```

Normally, it doesn't make a lot of sense to store the ID inside the JSON object redundantly. But you seem to have your reasons.

The reverse, ***removing*** a (top-level!) key from `jsonb` is even simpler:

```
SELECT meta - 'id' FROM people;
```

Or:

```
UPDATE people
SET    id = (meta->>'id')::int  -- to set id
     , meta = meta - 'id'       -- to *also* remove from jsonb
;
```

The **`-`** operator for `jsonb` as left operand and `text` as right operand is [defined as follows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

> Delete key/value pair or *string* element from left operand. Key/value pairs are matched based on their key value.

[The manual on the used function and operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

If there is no key named 'id' or you get `NULL` instead - which would not be legal for a notnull column ...

Comment: That's great, thanks.

Can I ask how you would do the reverse? (Set a value in the parent row from the child jsonb column)

Comment: @JMurphyWeb: I added the reverse operation above.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks 